# Slider with carousel image slider

Tags: jquery

I need a code for making a carousel slider that have an auto scroll option and scroll buttons in the image , can you can provide it with jquery ,css,html ?

```
            <div>

                 <a href="#">    <img src="img/13.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Hot mixer" /> </a>


            </div>
            <div>

                 <a href="#">    <img src="" alt="Image Alternative text" title="iPhone 5 iPad mini iPad 3" /> </a>

            </div>

           <div>

                  <a href="">  <img src="img/12.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Branding  iPad Interactive Design" /></a>

            </div>

        </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL for the Carousel - dynamic number of slides

https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery plugins](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/). There are a number of plugins available on this page with demos and documentation.